# Could not replace field values in my json object as per the list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have below list

```
categories=[{'Housing': 1}, {'Movies': 2}, {'Banking': 3}, {'Restaurant': 4}, {'Travel': 5}]
```

I would like to replace name field of below dataset with the value from above categories list.

```
categories_src=[
{'id':0,'name':'Banking'},
{'id':1,'name':'Home'},
{'id':2,'name':'Travel'},
{'id':3,'name':'Movies'}
]
```

I tried with below, but it is not working for strings.. 
I could use it for integer fields..

```
    categories ={2:1,3:4,4:8,5:12,6:16,7:20,8:40,9:80,10:100}
    for cat in categories_src:
        cat['id']=categories[cat['id']]
```

I couldn't use this for strings, how can I get as required such that name field in my source dataset is replaced with values for the categories ?

If I can convert below list to Dictionary, I think it should work. I tried but unsuccessful with dict()

```
 categories=[{'Housing': 1}, {'Movies': 2}, {'Banking': 3}, {'Restaurant': 4}, {'Travel': 5}]
```

How can I make above list to be converted as dictionary as below?

```
categories={'Housing': 1, 'Movies': 2, 'Banking': 3, 'Restaurant': 4, 'Travel': 5}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using dict comprehensions:

```
>>> {key:x[key] for x in categories for key in x} 
# {'Travel': 5, 'Restaurant': 4, 'Movies': 2, 'Banking': 3, 'Housing': 1}
```